# ErrorMsg in loading sample database from O'Reilly Media's "Learning SQL"

Tags: mysql, sql

[**Learning SQL, Second Edition**](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520830)

```
By Alan Beaulieu
Publisher: O'Reilly Media
Released: April 2009
ISBN: 9780596520830
```

The above book has code to create a MySQL database, which they've posted here:
http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596520847/LearningSQLExample.sql

When I run the code, everything "appears" to be fine, but only after I remove these lines of code:

```
/* recreate employee self-referencing foreign key */
alter table employee add constraint fk_e_emp_id
foreign key (superior_emp_id) references employee (emp_id);
```

I believe it's clear to me what the this code is doing, and that it was executed in the create table statements -- and appears to never been undone (so it's unclear to me why the code causing the error is needed); might be wrong about that.

Here's the error message I get for those lines of code, which is the same regardless if it's execute within the code linked to above, or in the case below, run after removing it from the supplied code, running the supplied code (which creates the database), and then running it on it's own on the created database:

```
Enter password: **********************************************************
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 17
Server version: 5.1.53-community MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to modify and redistribute it under the GPL v2 license

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use bank
Database changed
mysql> alter table employee add constraint fk_e_emp_id
    -> foreign key (superior_emp_id) references employee (emp_id);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'bank.#sql-80c_11' (errno: 121)
mysql>exit
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Just in case you're wondering, since I find the code a little strange, the book's instructions for using the code linked to are basically:

```
create database bank;
use bank
source C:\LearningSQLExample.sql;
```

---

Comment: The comment by Mike Cook in [this bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15324) may describe your situation.

Comment: @bobince: Thanks, looked at the comment by Mike Cook, and it roughly has to do with the issue -- in the since that once you've created a FK you are not able to create another FK with the same name. That said, his issue was different. He created a FK named for example FK_01, then dropped it, then attempt to reuse the FK name FK_01; which he was unable to do until he dropped and recreated the table that had the first reference to FK_01, which had been removed. Or at least that's my reading of it; which does not appear to related to the issue at hand. May I missing something? Again, thanks!

Comment: He appears to be describing a bug where, if you try to add a constraint with a clashing name, it not only fails (as expected) but also sabotages the table so any future attempts to ALTER it produce the error message.

Comment: @bobince: If that's what he's saying, I'm unable to duplicate the error, since "ALTER TABLE employee ADD email VARCHAR(60) FIRST;" works fine. Again, I believe he's saying that all FK names are cached until the table(s) using them are dropped, regardless if the FK is dropped by itself. It's not that clear though, so you might be right that's what he's saying; even though I'm not able to duplicate the error. I don't know how to drop an FK, so I can't test the reuse of an FK name after it's been dropped.

Comment: @bobince: I might add that even if what Mike Cook is saying is true, that sounds like a feature, not a bug; though the error message should be more clear to state that that FK name is reserved and requires a "super drop" to release it for reuse by other fields/tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no reason for that statement being there.

They are using a temp table to ensure that only valid FKs get assigned to the superior_emp_id column, so I can't imagine needing to drop the constraint and then re-add it.  My guess is they originally had code to do just that because of the way there were populating the employees table, but then rearranged the code to where it is now.  Eh, even that explanation might not make sense.

In any case, sloppy of them to not at least do a simple run through of the sample code before publishing.

Comment: +1 @Phil Sandler: So, it's correct that the foreign key constraint "fk_e_emp_id" was created when "employee" table was created. The "fk_e_emp_id" foreign key constraint was never dropped, but then for some reason it's in the code to be re-created, even though it was never removed; in which case one would hope this would return an error message; the problem is with the code; and the answer is to remove it. Right, or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I see no reason why you can't safely remove it.

Comment: +1 @Phil Sandler: Selected as the answer. Thanks for the clarification. I've returned the book, and don't think I would have ever bought it if I'd seen the code to create the database; which in my opinion looks like someone's notes for creating a dataset, and not a production ready dump.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unsigned deceleration in employee table for superior_emp_id and emp_id and try again.

In the table creation for employee:

```
create table employee
(emp_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment,
fname varchar(20) not null,
lname varchar(20) not null,
start_date date not null,
end_date date,
superior_emp_id smallint unsigned,
dept_id smallint unsigned,
title varchar(20),
assigned_branch_id smallint unsigned,
constraint fk_e_emp_id 
foreign key (superior_emp_id) references employee (emp_id),
constraint fk_dept_id
foreign key (dept_id) references department (dept_id),
constraint fk_e_branch_id
foreign key (assigned_branch_id) references branch (branch_id),
constraint pk_employee primary key (emp_id)
);
```

empid is marked as `unsigned`: `emp_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment` Try removing this `unsigned`.

Comment: make the Foreign key field as not unsigned.

Comment: @user328560: Not familiar with the term "unsigned deceleration" -- what are the line numbers of the code you're referencing and what needs to be removed. Thanks!

Comment: @user328560: Hey Rohit, fyi -- it's possible to edit the answer you posted by clicking "edit" - posted a update via a comment is not the approach suggested by stackoverflow unless you're responding to a question; and even then, if that results in a change to your answer it's normal to update the answer too. Cheers, and huge thanks for your help! Also, if you click "user328560" at the top of your screen, you should be able to edit your profile to have the username displayed as "Rohit"; that is if that's the username you want.

Comment: @user328560: what does the way the integer is declared have to do with the problem?

Comment: @learner: (aka user328560) -- thanks, working through those edits and testing them. Am wondering the same thing as Phil Sandler as to why removing "unsigned" will resolve the issue. Again, thanks -- and glad to see my comments were of use to you. Cheers!

Comment: @blunders
Glad to hear that and thanks for the suggestions. I am kinda new to stackoverflow. :)

Comment: @learner: So, tested removing "unsigned" from the FKs and fields referencing the FKs; which included a few other tables to the database beyond just the employee table; those being any table that reference those columns as FKs; for example, the "account" and "transaction" tables. These edits do not appear to have made a difference, since I'm still getting the same error message. Why should this change fix the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It is June 2016 and i am using MySQL Community Server 5.7.13 on Win7 PC

First,
Add `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` as shown below

```
/* create data for self-referencing foreign key 'superior_emp_id' */

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

create temporary table

```
emp_tmp as select emp_id, fname, lname from employee;
```

etc

Second,
Remove **unsigned** from any place it appears in the code.

The code works like a charm with these mods.